# Prove that $0\leq (\mathbb{E}[X])\leq (\mathbb{E}[X^2])^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq (\mathbb{E}[X^3])^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq ...$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let X be a random non-negative variable, prove that
$0\leq (\mathbb{E}[X])\leq (\mathbb{E}[X^2])^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq (\mathbb{E}[X^3])^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq ...$

I know that $0\leq \mathbb{E}[X]$ can be proved with Markov's inequality, but what about the other part?

Comment: This is known as the Power Mean inequality.

Comment: Not sure what does Markov Inequality have to do with anything here. You should use Holder's inequality.

Answer (score 3):

This can be proved directly using Jensen's Inequality:

Let $k$ be a positive integer and $X$ a nonnegative real-valued random variable. We show the inequality $\mathbb{E}[X^{k}]^{\frac{1}{k}}$  $\mathbb{E}[X^{k+1}]^{\frac{1}{k+1}}$ Note that this gives the desired result.

To this end, let us set $Z=X^k$. Then on the one hand, $X^{k+1} = Z^{\frac{k+1}{k}}$. On the other hand, Jensen's gives
$$ \mathbb{E}[Z]^{\frac{k+1}{k}}\  \le  \ \mathbb{E}[Z^{\frac{k+1}{k}}].$$
Thus taking the $\frac{1}{k+1}$-th power of both sides yields:

$$ \mathbb{E}[Z]^{\frac{1}{k}}\  \le  \ \mathbb{E}[Z^{\frac{k+1}{k}}]^{\frac{1}{k+1}}.$$

So plugging in $Z=X^k$ and [as observed above] $Z^{\frac{k+1}{k}}=X^{k+1}$ yields indeed

$$ \mathbb{E}[X^k]^{\frac{1}{k}}\  \le  \ \mathbb{E}[X^{k+1}]^{\frac{1}{k+1}},$$ which as observed above, gives us the desired result.